# EntityFramework Trying to create multiple links to the same table, FK Constraint error

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table called DeliveryRequest and another table called Operator, table DeliveryRequest is as follows:

```
public class DeliveryRequest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Waybill { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("Operator")]
    public int SenderID { get; set; }
    public Operator Sender { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("Operator")]
    public int ReceiverID { get; set; }
    public Operator Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

And table Operator is as follows:

```
public class Operator
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

So the problem is, when I am trying to update my database I get a FK Constraint error as follows:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.DeliveryRequests_dbo.Operators_SenderID' on table
>   'DeliveryRequests' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints.
>       Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

And the previous error is the same. As follows:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.DeliveryRequests_dbo.Operators_SenderID' on
>   table 'DeliveryRequests' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Focus on the Sender and Receiver part, I am no expert but the error must be there lol

```
//[ForeignKey("Operator")]
public int SenderID { get; set; }
public Operator Sender { get; set; }
//[ForeignKey("Operator")]
public int ReceiverID { get; set; }
public Operator Receiver { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `Code First` approach. So try to turn off CascadeDelete for `DeliveryRequests`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryRequests>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Operator )
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

For example:

```
public class YourDBContext: DbContext 
{
    public YourDBContext(): base() 
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryRequests>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Operator )
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);    
    }
}
```